# Long-haired cat has poop caked on butt

Tags: cats, behavior, defecation, senior-pet, bathing

I have a 10 year old long-haired cat and for the very first time.

Now it is an absolute mess!  She Will NOT tolerate a bath.

I've always had dogs. So this is new to me.

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Will she let you wipe her with unscented baby wipes? They sell "pet wipes" too, but they're the same thing only more expensive. Unscented is the key. If she won't let you do that, either,  you may have to take her to a groomer or the vet to trim the fur on her hind-quarters.  When my long haired cat was older, she didn't have the flexibility or energy to keep herself clean, and trimming the fur was a big help to her.

Answer (score 0):

> She Will NOT tolerate a bath. I've always had dogs.

Cats generally don't like water - especially not when it's not their own decision.

Dogs are able to defer to humans and do something that the human tells them to do. Cats generally don't and rely on their own decisions.

Cats generally also don't need baths, they are self-cleaning animals. The poop getting stuck in their fur is something that needs to be addressed, but I suggest not using baths as a solution as it will lead to an unhappy cat, it may start to avoid coming near you.

---

Dealing with the poops getting stuck in her fur is an annoying problem.

In the short term, I suggest cutting the hair in which the poop is stuck to fix the issue. Just focus on the hard to get bits. Simple cleaning can be done by the cat herself (and I'm pretty sure it would prefer doing it herself).

In the long term, if your cat reasonably allows you to (or you can get her to endure it), I suggest trimming/cutting the hair on her posterior to prevent poop getting stuck in it. It doesn't need to be shaven off but keeping it to a reasonable length (like short haired cats) will prevent the issue.

Our long-haired cat used to have this issue once in a while, and her immediate reaction would be to drag her butt across surfaces to get it off. I think you can imagine the poop smears we can home to in those cases.
So what we did was get a very bristly floor mat ([example](https://www.americanfloormats.com/content/product/description/large/Bristle%20Brush%20Entrance%20Mats%20Grey%20Scrape%20600.jpg)) and put it next to the litter box. We had to replace the mat once it a while as it would get disgusting but it was considerably better than having to clean poop streaks off the floor and furniture.